# Is there any problem with using export keyword in real flutter apps

Tags: flutter, dart

I found myself splitting my work into a lot of other files, which causes a huge number of imports on main files, I know that the `export` keyword will help on this to avoid that, but when I search, I found that it's used mostly in libraries but not flutter apps,

my question is: is export `keyword` can be used on flutter apps normally like libraries or is there any kind of problems or reasons to avoid using it, and just deal with the normal import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good practice is to use `barrel files`. So the idea is to create the file inside your folder and `export` all the widgets / files that you have in this folder (using `export` keyword). In result you will reduce the number of your imports and make project more readable.
Flutter is so inteligent that using `barrel files` does not touch performance.

Comment: thanks, but is it recommended to use exports in real flutter apps or not

Comment: What do you mean 'real'? I am using them in my commercial projects as well as in tutorials that I create. Yes, it is recommended. Also it is a part of BLoC concept of architecture.